# If text of textbox is selected then make it null

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I use `meiomask` for time masking.masking is working perfectlly on keypress event.

Now the problem is when i am in first textbox  and then i press tab so now  the focus is on second textbox and it's value is selected(as you see in image).now if i try to enter some value in this textbox then the  focus is out of this textbox.so to enter value in this textbox every time i remove value using backspace then enter value in the textbox.

[image]

so basically i am trying to do is on focus of textbox, if textbox value is selected and user try to enter some thing(on keypress event) then make it null.so how to achieve this thing?
Thanks in advance.

`code:`

```
$(document).on('focus','.masktime',function(){
     // $(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: Currently you pass a string to `isTextSelected()`, but that function doesn't treat it as a string (it seems to expect you to pass a reference to a DOM element).

Comment: can you provide fiddle with your code please..

Comment: @nnnnnn what is the solution for that?

Comment: @DS9 the solution seems to pass DOM node, not string: `if(isTextSelected(this)){...}` And BTW, keypress event is not fired for TAB key, keyup event is. I'm not sure to understand exactly what you are looking for. Providing a jsfiddle would help you in order to get more accurate answer.

Comment: Use placeholders, instead of giving your input tags default values. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/KH8uA/)

Comment: in update time, i have to display inserted time into textbox, so i can't use placeholder.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/KH8uA/2/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use placeholders...so,

```
<input class="masktime" type="text" placeholder="00:00">
```

instead of

```
<input class="masktime" type="text" value="00:00">
```

Or, if you wish to use the `value` of the input tag at all times, you can emulate the behaviour of an `input[placeholder]` using a combination of `focus` and `blur`.

```
$('.masktime').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).attr('oldVal', $(this).val());
    $(this).val('');
});
$('.masktime').on('blur', function () {
    if($(this).val()=='') {
        $(this).val($(this).attr('oldVal'));
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/KH8uA/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much it's useful for me and what is `oldVal` attribute?

Comment: It's a custom attribute. You can call it anything you want.